# OpenOffice Writer: getting a "Measurement at" value in the status bar

Tags: openoffice-writer, libreoffice-writer

In Microsoft Office there's a *Measurement at* value displayed in the status bar which measures the distance of the current line to the  upper margin (in centimeters).

See [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/items-that-appear-in-the-status-bar-HP005190083.aspx).

Is there any way to get the same thing in OO/LibreOffice?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to display a horizontal and vertical ruler at the top and left of your document, however it doesn't seem to allow you to correlate the location of the insertion point to an actual value. (In other words, it seems cosmetic.)

You can select from the menu, **View → Ruler** to enable it. Or, if you go to **Preferences → OpenOffice.org Writer → View** you can enable either axes and configure the measurement units displayed.

I've often wondered this too, I'll update this entry if I find a better way, but I think you're SOL. (I'm using OO 3.3.0.)

Comment: thanks. But I already knew that. I took the liberty to ask the same in a OO forum, see [here](http://user.services.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=45129). It seems that's  currently a missing feature